# How to use triple quotation marks for inline JS in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page where I can't use `<script></script>` and I have to place inline JS within the HTML.

I'm having trouble finding a triple quotation to change the css `background-image` URL via JS where I'm already using single and double quotation marks e.g.

```html
<div onmouseover='document.getElementById("anotherDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url("https://www.test.com/image.jpg")";"></div>
```

where I need a triple quotation mark to wrap:

```js
url("walrus-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/20-test-1.jpg")
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: you can try `&quot;`

Comment: Or use CSS instead of assigning style properties.

Comment: Use a backslash to escape quotes within Javascript code. Use `&quot;` to encode quotes within HTML attributes.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus unfortunately does not work. I get a `caught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier '` where it does not recognize the image URL. @Barmar using `:hover` won't work either as I'm trying to change the `background-image` of another div

Comment: @Chris, you actually don't need quotes for the URL. `"url(https://...)"` should work just fine.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus no quote for the URL and deceze's backslashing both work! thank you

Comment: `"\"\"\"url(\"walrus-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/img/20-test-1.jpg\")\"\"\""`. HTH.

Comment: You can use [`.cssText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText) property. ex. `<button onclick='document.getElementById("x").cssText = "background: #000 url(https://example.com/icon.png) no-repeat center contain; height: 48px; width: 48px;"'>X</button>;` CSS ruleset property/values (ie the styles between the brackets `{...}` (ex `selector {property: value; property: value}`)), syntax doesn't require quotes AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add quotation for url(), do this

```
 <div onmouseover="document.getElementById('anotherDiv').style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://www.test.com/image.jpg)'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet but as the others say, prefer a css and create a listener in the script tags to change the style like in the second snippet or in the third snippet if the script is in the head tags.

```html
<div id = "anotherDiv" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color:#995500;"></div>
    <div onmouseover="document.getElementById('anotherDiv').style.backgroundImage='url(https://dummyimage.com/200x100/666666/fff)'" style="cursor: pointer;">mouse over to change the background and use an image.
    </div>
```

Second snippet :

```js
        let mOverDiv = document.getElementById("mOverDiv");
        let anotherDiv = document.getElementById("anotherDiv");
        mOverDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", changeStyle);
        function changeStyle(e){
            anotherDiv.style.backgroundImage='url(https://dummyimage.com/200x100/666666/fff)';
        }
```

```css
        #anotherDiv{
            width:200px;
            height:100px;
            background-color:#996600;
        }
        #mOverDiv{
            cursor:pointer;
        }
```

```html
    <div id = "anotherDiv"></div>
    <div id = "mOverDiv">text in div</div>
```

If your script is declared inside the head section, use this third snippet. Therefore you wait that the content is loaded before to assign the 'divs' tags and the listener :

```js
        let mOverDiv;
        let anotherDiv;
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",addListener);
        function addListener(e){
            mOverDiv = mOverDiv = document.getElementById("mOverDiv");
            anotherDiv = document.getElementById("anotherDiv");
            mOverDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", changeStyle);
        }
        function changeStyle(e){
            anotherDiv.style.backgroundImage='url(https://dummyimage.com/200x100/666666/fff)';
        }
```

```css
        #anotherDiv{
            width:200px;
            height:100px;
            background-color:#996600;
        }
        #mOverDiv{
            cursor:pointer;
        }
```

```html
    <div id = "anotherDiv"></div>
    <div id = "mOverDiv">text in div</div>
```

Comment: This is the better solution instead of JS in a string that writes CSS